# Prevent scrolling on load page

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

When loading my site http://www.confidences-lesalon.com/, the page scroll down or I want the left scroll should not scrolling. Is there any custom CSS or JavaScript code to prevent it from scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

You are loading 24 JavaScripts on this page, so figuring out which is creating your situation will involve some work. The easiest solution is to add a 25th JavaScript that scrolls back to the top:

```
(function() {
  window.scrollTo(0,0)
})();
```

Comment: i have copied it into header .php either footer.php but no changes , it's still scrolling down when refreshing  page

Comment: it works when i changed it to :  jQuery(window).load(function() {
   window.scrollTo(0,0);
});

Comment: @prestadev perfect. It's been years since I worked with jQuery but the IIFE style above is usually perfect on non-jQuery sites. In any event, I hope that helps.